# Change attributes of a follow button to unfollow button attributes on ajax

Tags: php, ajax, attributes

Sorry if this is a duplicate, but I've been searching for a while, only found a solution to change text or class, so I don't know if this is possible, I just need someone to point me in the right direction on what to do or how to do it.

I have two buttons, one with follow attributes that I send to Ajax to execute a function and another unfollow which does similar but executes the opposite function. I included a code which I used to identify a user to follow or unfollow, it changes between the two buttons but only when I refresh the page, I was wondering if there was a way to have the new attributes of the unfollow button when I have successfully followed a user or unfollowed without the page refresh.

Here's my code of both delegations on ajax

2. To follow a user

   ```
     $("body").delegate("#user_click_id","click",function(event){
    var user_user_id = $(this).attr("user_user_id");
    event.preventDefault();
    $(".overlay").show();
    $.ajax ({
        url: "action.php",
        method : "POST",
        data:{Userfollow:1,user_user_id:1,user_off_id:user_user_id},
        success: function(data){
        $("#follow_msg").html(data);
        $(".overlay").hide();
        count_user_following();
    }       })   })
   ```
3. To unfollow a user

   ```
      $("body").delegate("#remove_user_click_id","click",function(event){
    var user_unfollow_id = $(this).attr("user_unfollow_id");
    event.preventDefault();
    var data =$(this).serialize();
    swal({
          title: "Are you sure?",
          text:"You are about to unfollow this user!",
           type:"warning",
           confirmButtonText:"Yes, Unfollow",
           cancelButtonText:"Cancel",
           closeOnConfirm:false,
           closeOnCancel:false,
           showCancelButton:true
     },
          function (isConfirm) {
              if(isConfirm){
    $(".overlay").show();
    $.ajax ({
        url: "action.php",
        method : "POST",
        data:{UnfollowUser:1,user_remove_id:1,user_off_id:user_unfollow_id},
        success: function(data){
        swal("Unfollowed","You successfully unfollowed this user","success");
        $(".overlay").hide();
        count_user_following();
     },error:function(data){
       swal("Unsuccessful","something went wrong, please try again","error");
       $.('.overlay').hide();
        count_user_following();
      }
      });
      }else{ 
         swal("You Cancelled","You are still following this user","error");
          count_user_following();
        }
      });
     })
   ```

So both buttons having attributes highlighted in both functions are given below

1. Follow attribute on button

   ```
     <a user_user_id=<?=$user_user_id?> id="user_click_id" class="follow">Follow</a>
   ```
2. Unfollow attributes on button

   ```
      <a user_unfollow_id=<?=$user_user_id?> id="remove_user_click_id" class="unfollow">Unfollow</a>
   ```

So my problem is getting them to switch between the follow and unfollow only after success while maintaining the highlighted attributes, I can change the class and text, but the "user_unfollow_id" to "user_user_id" is what I'm having a problem changing. Maybe I'm just missing something.. Please any step in the right direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Just a warning, all of the code below is untested...

Your two jQuery functions are almost identical. To keep things [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), why not combine everything into one?

Instead of using two different buttons, use one button that acts as a toggle. On or off.

```
  <a data-state="not-followed" user_user_id=<?=$user_user_id?> id="user_click_id" class="follow">Follow</a>
```

When the user clicks the follow link, a few things can then happen:

In your js, check the value of data-state. If it is "not-followed" then we process a follow request. If it is "followed" then we do an unfollow request. We can modify the values in the link after each press:

```
$("body").delegate("#user_click_id","click",function(event){

    event.preventDefault();

    var user_user_id = $(this).attr("user_user_id");
    var state = $(this).data('state'); // get the state from the data attribute

    $(".overlay").show();

    $.ajax ({
        url: "action.php",
        method : "POST",
        data:{
            state: state,
            userFollow:1,
            user_insert_id: 1, // not sure what this is for
            user_new_id: <?=$user_user_id>
        },
        success: function(data){
            $("#follow_msg").html(data);
            $(".overlay").hide();
            count_user_following();

            // now update the link
            $(this).text(state == 'followed' ? 'unfollow' : 'follow');
            // and update the data-state attribute
            $(this).data('state',state == 'followed' ? 'not-followed' : 'followed')
        }
    })
})
```

So you send both follow and unfollow requests to the same place. Then when the request hits the server, just check to see if `state` is "follow" or "unfollow" and do the appropriate thing with the other variables that have been sent.

Comment: I think there will be a Lil problem,, while trying not to lengthen the code, I think I omitted a little which made the two request look a little similar, so I'm aware of the DRY issue.. Let me re-edit.. Because in the unfollow.. I'm kinda using a sweetalert to make it look nice.. So wondering if it can still be employed using this method..

Comment: I have edited the code.. Please take a look and tell me if I can do same??